# How to reopen a very same activity / how to keep an activity alive?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a main activity and there I start a new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

To go back to the main activity I used the finish() method.

My question is: How is it possible to switch to the very same second Activity without starting a new one? I thougt the finish() method kills the second Activity, but it still works how the code is telling him (timer counts down and a sound appears) in the background . So is it possible to just switch back to the second Activity on Screen?

In the past I had used a TabWidget which works also with activities, so it it must be possible in some way!? Or do I have to use Fragments? But if I use Fragments I have the same question: How to keep the Fragment alive till I have to use it again?

I hope you can help me with this, that would be great.
I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` when starting the `SecondActivity.class`.

It will basically tell Android to search the backstack for an instance of `SecondActivity`. If such instance is found it'll move it to the top of the stack.

Also keep in mind that if you call `finish()` on your SecondActivity, the `REORDER_TO_FRONT` flag practically won't do anything, as you'll never have live instances of the Activity.

Comment: thank you for you answer this helped me a lot, but when I use the android "Back Button" (the Arrow in the left corner) it seems that the second Activity is automaticly finished. Can I change this?

Comment: You can if you overwrite onBackPressed() method, but generally it's not a good idea to do so. Why do you insists on reusing the same activity? Is it super hard and complicated and thus takes a long time to instantiate?

Comment: the second activity has a countdown and this should also run in the background when the user go back to the main activity, so I can't just recreate the second activity with the same variables.

Comment: Than use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() - they'll fit perfect for your situation if I understand it correctly :) Read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: but onSaveInstanceState() will stop the activity right? So the countdown would also stop until the user goes back to the second Activity?

Comment: Sorry, I just read  your previous comment again more carefully. "has a countdown and this should also run in the background when the user go back to the main activity" - this clearly says you need some sort of a Service to accomplish it. If you need to ensure some stuff works on the background while the activity is NOT in the foreground - you surely need a service of some sort. Can't you move this "timer logic" to a Service and just bind to it from the Activities you need? I know I'm not giving you ready decision right away, but I'm just pointing you to the right direction.

Comment: As for the onSaveInstanceState() -> this will be called automatically by the system when the activity finishes. The idea of the method is to save some "state" of the Activity you might want to return to in the future. For example   if you wanted to save the current value of a counter you'd do it here. Than you can resume your "counting" from this value the next time.

Comment: Thank you very much Vesko you helped me a lot. :D

Answer (score 1):

If your activity is alive you can resume it by this code:

```
    Intent openMainActivity= new Intent(SomeActivity.this, Main.class));
    openMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

Or you can clear other activities with this flag:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```